# Cerrar un libro de trabajo excel desde una aplicacion a nivel de documento con VSTO y VB.NET

Tags: visual-studio, excel

Tengo una aplicación a nivel de documento excel creada bajo VSTO y VB.net. Al arrancar la aplicación presenta un formulario, el cual tiene un botón para cerrar el libro activo. El código que debo emplear para cerrar el libro activo desde el formulario es mi reto, ya que he intentado de todo pero siempre me sale un error que deja congelado el excel. La única opción que cierra efectivamente el libro es el método quit, pero este método cierra toda la aplicación y no solamente el libro activo que en mi caso es lo que necesito. Alguna sugerencia en lenguaje vb.net?

Comment: Los objetos workbook tienen una propiedad `Close`. ¿No puedes cerrar el archivo con eso?  https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido. No sé si te servirá, pero yo siempre que trabajo con un fichero Excel en Vb, para cerrarlo y trabajar con él, siempre suelo hacer lo siguiente:
Declaro las variables relacionadas con Excel:

```
    ' -- Variables para Excel   
    Dim Obj_Excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim Obj_Libro As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim Obj_Hoja As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
```

Una vez que copio, agrego o hago lo pedido en el fichero, para cerralo, tras generarlo, hago lo siguiente:

```
 Obj_Excel.Visible = True

            Obj_Hoja = Nothing
            Obj_Libro = Nothing
            Obj_Excel = Nothing
```

Con la propiedad visible en true, lo que hago es generar el archivo, y luego, tras asignar Nothing a las variables hoja, libro, excel, lo que hago es dejarlas sin  nada.

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, no das detalles, pero podrías usar la clase Globals y el método Close, algo así:

Globals.ThisWorkbook.Close(False)